# Trying to work out how to escape a hyphen in an XML Tag in Azure SQL Analytics

Tags: azure-sql-database

working with Kusto / KQL to try and parse the deadlock xml in Azure SQL Analytics and getting stuck with escaping the tag name process-list as follows

So the deadlock xml looks like

```
<deadlock>
  <process-list>
  ...
```

I want to get one of the attributes under process-list but KQL chokes on the hyphen and I don't know how to escape it to make it work - see the bold section in the last line

AzureDiagnostics
| where (Category == "Deadlocks")
| where ResourceId contains "/SERVERS/"
| where ResourceId contains "/DATABASES/"
| where Resource contains "Analytics"
| project Resource = strcat(extract(".+/SERVERS/([^/]+)/.+", 1, ResourceId), ".", extract(".+/DATABASES/(.+)", 1, ResourceId)).tolower(), TimeGenerated, deadlock_xml_s
| extend DeadlockXML = parse_xml(deadlock_xml_s)
| extend KeyDeets = DeadlockXML.deadlock.**process-list**.waitresource

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *...but KQL chokes on the hyphen and I don't know how to escape it to make it work*

Please see: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/schema-entities/entity-names#identifier-quoting

for example: `DeadlockXML.deadlock['process-list'].waitresource`

Comment: Thanks, I should have included more of the xml I realise - to get it working how I wanted I ended up with the below :-

| extend KeyDeets = DeadlockXML.deadlock.['process-list'].process[1]["@waitresource"]